# how to combine cron expressions?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a task which requires to be executed every Thursday, but if the day is a speical holiday such as Christmas, the task should be changed to another day( wednesday or friday), so I get is a general expression plus some special dates, how should I combine all these expressions in one cron expression to be used in Quartz? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with just one expression since there's no way to specify holidays.

But you can define two triggers **T1** and **T2** and a "smarter" Job **J1**:

- A trigger **T1** on **J1** that fires every *Thursday* using the [HolidayCalendar](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/calendar/HolidayCalendar.html) that will exclude arbitrary days from triggering the job execution

  ```
  //Define an HolidayCalendar and add it to Scheduler
  HolidayCalendar cal = new HolidayCalendar();
  cal.addExcludedDate( someDate );
  sched.addCalendar("myHolidays", cal, false);

  //Create the trigger T1 to use the holydayCalendar
  ...
  triggerT1.setCalendarName("myHolidays");

  //schedule job with trigger T1
  ```
- Define a Trigger **T2** on **J1** that fires on the alterantive day you choose (Wednesday or Friday).
- The job **J1** must decide whether start executing its business logic or not using the HolydayCalendar. There are many easy ways to do this, for exemple:

  ```
  //Get Holyday calendar from Scheduler instance
  HolidayCalendar cal = sched.getCalendar("myHolidays");

  //Decide here if execute or not
  if (today is an "alternative" day && lastThursday is an holiday) {
       //Job real business logic
  }
  ```

See this [Quartz tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson04) for more exemple about Quartz Calendars.

Also you can use [this tool](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to build Quartz-compatible Cron expressions.

Hope this helps!